# 4x4 keypad stops reacting

Tags: keypad

I am having an issue with the a 4×4 keypad. It usually works fine but sometimes the keypad stops reacting or no key is pressed but it still shows a random keypress on the LCD. The only solution is to unplug and plug again. I thought it may be the length of the wires for the keypad. I uses 3 ft wires from the keypad to the Arduino. Has anyone faced similar issues? 
[image: Diagram]
[image: Picture1]
[image: Keypad]

Comment: 3' is not that long really, but the internal pullups of the Arduino are quite weak, and you are in what looks like a noisy (electrically speaking) environment. So maybe it is EMI causing things to happen that you don't want to happen. Consider making the keypad a standalone system with a balanced communication system between that and the main box.

Comment: The keypad and the LCD need to be connected to the arduino. I can power 5V to the LCD from a separate source, but the keypad has to be connected to the arduino.

Comment: What I am suggesting is have an Arduino (one of the small ones?) connected directly to the keypad (very short wires then), and use a serial protocol (rs232, rs485, etc) to connect that Arduino to the existing Arduino.

Comment: Try to test with Arduino, keypad, and LCD only to make sure that other components do not affect them. You can refer to [Arduino - Keypad - LCD tutorial](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-keypad-lcd)